# pH(H3O+ ion concentration) of a mixture of 2 weak acids

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium

I need to find out the $\ce{H3O+}$ ion concentration in a mixture of 2 weak acids $\ce{HA1}$ and $\ce{HA2}$.

They will be ionised as 
$$\ce{HA1 + H2O <=> A1- + H3O+}$$
And
$$\ce{HA2 + H2O <=> A2- + H3O+}$$

Then, if $c_1$ and $c_2$ are the concentration of the acids and their dissociation constants are $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$,then how much will be the value of $[\ce{H3O+}]$ ?

The textbook states without proof  that it is approximately equal to $\sqrt{(K_{1}c_{1} +K_{2}c_{2})}$.

Any help on how to approach the result is appreciated.

Comment: If they are weak acids then how come they ionize (not dissociate) irreversibly?

Comment: @user34388 sorry for the error. They ionize only like any other weak acid.pls check, I have edited the question